# Progress Indicator Path

Tags: lightning-progressindicator

I building a custom progress builder, if my stage is closed lost all the stages before my closed stage is appearing in green , but in standard component it not showing green color.

Image :
[image]

my code:

```
 <lightning:progressIndicator currentStep="{!v.CurrentStep}" type="path" variant="base">
                        <aura:iteration items="{! v.AllStagesList }" var="step">
                            <aura:if isTrue="{!step != 'Closed Lost'}">                
                                <lightning:progressStep class="slds-is-incomplete" label="{! step }" value="{! step }" onclick="{!c.onClickProgressIndicatorSteps}"/>
                                <aura:set attribute="else">
                                    <lightning:progressStep class="slds-is-lost" label="{! step }" value="{! step }" onclick="{!c.onClickProgressIndicatorSteps}"/>
                                </aura:set>
                            </aura:if>
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </lightning:progressIndicator>
```

Plz help!!

Comment: Your `progressStep` is using the `slds-is-incomplete` class.  Change that class accordingly to either show nothing or a green completed stage (like `slds-is-complete`)

Comment: @BrianMiller how to make a ProgressIndicator grey background once it is closed lost

Comment: I thought `slds-is-incomplete` would do the trick.  Try google chrome inspecting the standard component on those path items to see what `slds` classes they're using.

Comment: Also, I would edit your question to indicate that you want the grey background items - I didn't realize that's what you wanted from the original question

Comment: @BrianMiller I wiill try chrome inspecting

Comment: it is not working they have used ```slds-is-incomplete```

Comment: Inspect your html code and try to find the difference in classes.  Otherwise not sure :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if Progress Indicator is the component you want for your UX needs. Progress Indicator is meant to show linear progression, where all previously completed steps are meant to be successful. It doesn't support a concept of "Lost", and you would not have the ability to suppress the "slds-is-complete" class on previous steps (it's baked into the component, and its presence intentionally overrides css declarations applied to "slds-is-incomplete").

For your needs, you really need to use the Path component. This component is tailored towards those user interface states, and was designed to support the case you have.

Please check out the documentation here to get more information about the Path component:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:path/documentation